# か at the end of a news story title. Is it a question?

Tags: translation, particle-か, modality

The title of [a story on NHK News Web Easy](http://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/easy/k10010409381000/k10010409381000.html) is

> バスの事故{じこ}　スピードを上{あ}げながら走{はし}り続{つづ}けた**か**

Which, with my abilities, translates as

> Bus accident. As speed increased it kept running?

I don't understand why that か is there at the end of the sentence though. Is the title of the story actually a question? Or does this signify something else? Frankly I'm not even sure my translation is correct. It seems an odd thing to say, since a speed increase would seem to imply that of course the bus kept running. If the bus wasn't running, the speed would go down, generally speaking.

Comment: 新聞や雑誌の記事の見出しには、「～かもしれない・可能性がある」「～かどうか不明」「～ではないかと疑われている」という意味で、「XXか」と書かれることがよくあります。

Comment: @choco: そのコメントは私のためにですか？翻訳は時間がかかります。

Comment: @choco: I think I got it. In newspaper and magazine headlines, when an event X is uncertain, it will be written as 「Xか」. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this か marks a question.  An alternative translation might help clarify:

> Bus accident: did [the driver / the bus] keep accelerating?

This is clearly the question the police are asking in the article -- the bus was coming down a roughly 1km (probably steep) downhill grade, and at the time of the accident, the bus was moving at 96kph, nearly double to 50kph speed limit.

**Translation note:** The bit スピードを上げながら走り続けた literally breaks down as *"continued running while increasing the speed"*.  This is idiomatic as Japanese, but not as English -- the underlying meaning is *continued accelerating*, since the *driving* or *running* part is clear in the English, and explicitly stating it sounds odd: one cannot make a vehicle accelerate without driving.